# YouTube API onClick скрыть или показать элементы управления

Tags: youtube-api, click, controls

Доброго времени суток, есть такой вот код:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ytplayer"></div>
<script>
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
    var player;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
            playerVars: {
                autoplay: 1,
                controls: 0,
                loop: 1,
                rel: 0,
                showinfo: 0},
            videoId: '-vH2eZAM30s',
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        player.mute();
        $('#ytplayer').on('click', function() {
            player.unMute();
        });
    }
    var done = false;
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    }
</script>
```

Изначально видео автоматически запускается без звука, по нажатию на плеер, звук возвращается.
Но вот хочу еще, что бы по нажатию отобразило панель управления (т.е. controls: 1).
Как это сделать?

Comment: На данный момент в YouTube Iframe API не предусмотрено метода для динамического  управления controls

Comment: Хорошо, как на счет скрытия и отображения? Этим можно управлять?

Comment: Скрытия и отображения чего и когда? Можно при инициализации плеера - либо показывать панель управления (controls), либо нет. Во время работы штатных средств YoutTube API  не предусмотрено пока